# Pass Dynamic connection string to another Windows Form (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, connection-string

I am creating a windows application which required Dynamic Connection String in the app starting (user need to provide db credentials through a form), After entering the connection credentials user redirected to new win form
Everything is working fine but how can I pass my dynamic connection to another form.

I tried to save it to App variable but I couldn't (I think its read only)
Also I tried save it to  registry but can't retrieve values.

Is there any other option available ? like writing & retrieving ConString to a text file or XML

Thanks

Comment: There's only one connection string.  So making it Shared is a simple approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how you can get and set registry values :

```
Public Function GetRegistryValue(ByVal KeyName As String, Optional ByVal DefaultValue As Object = Nothing) As Object
        Dim res As Object = Nothing
        Try
            Dim k = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\YourAppName", True)
            If k IsNot Nothing Then
                res = k.GetValue(KeyName, DefaultValue)
            Else
                k = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\YourAppName")
            End If
            If k IsNot Nothing Then k.Close()
        Catch ' ex As Exception
            'PromptMsg(ex)
        End Try
        Return res
End Function

Public Sub SetRegistryValue(ByVal KeyName As String, ByVal _Value As Object)
        Try
            Dim k = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\YourAppName", True)
            If k IsNot Nothing Then
                k.SetValue(KeyName, _Value)
            Else
                k = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\YourAppName")
                k.SetValue(KeyName, _Value)
            End If
            If k IsNot Nothing Then k.Close()
        Catch ' ex As Exception
            'PromptMsg(ex)
        End Try
End Sub
```

It's working a 100%, If you please mark this answer as **Right**